# Service upstrart process exited with error code

Tags: ubuntu, go, daemon, supervisord, upstart

I added ponzu-server in upstart, but I start ponzu-server  have some error.

```
sudo service ponzu-server start
Job for ponzu-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ponzu-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

journalctl -xe:

```
Jan 28 19:12:22 cs67724 systemd[1]: ponzu-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 28 19:12:22 cs67724 systemd[1]: ponzu-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 28 19:12:22 cs67724 sudo[1069]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 28 19:12:30 cs67724 sudo[1095]:    ponzu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ponzu/work ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Jan 28 19:12:30 cs67724 sudo[1095]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ponzu(uid=0)
Jan 28 19:13:14 cs67724 sudo[1095]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 28 19:16:58 cs67724 sudo[1118]:    ponzu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ponzu/work/src/remoteConfig/deployment/sysv ; USER=root ; COMM
Jan 28 19:16:58 cs67724 sudo[1118]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ponzu(uid=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly caused by not assigning the $VARIABLES in the init script that is provided as an example in the Ponzu project.

Make sure you add your own project directory path and other variables before you try to start a daemon/service.

Comment: Sure thing -- if you wouldn't mind then marking my answer correct or adding your own solution and marking it, it would be helpful to other people who find this from a Google search.